# What does "@" mean in bind zone file?

Tags: bind

Usually after `$TTL` and `$ORIGIN` there is a line starting with `@` and `IN` in zone name then email address of admin, what does `@` mean here and in the next entries?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$ORIGIN` is used in two contexts during zone file processing:

1. **The symbol @ forces substitution of the current (or synthesized) value of $ORIGIN. The @ symbol is replaced with the current value of $ORIGIN.**
2. The current value of `$ORIGIN` is added to any 'unqualified' name (any name which does not end in a 'dot').

Example of `@` symbol replacement:

```
; example.com zone file fragment 
; no $ORIGIN present and is synthesized from the 
; zone name in named.conf
....
@          IN      NS     ns1.example.com. 
; ns1.example.com is the name server for example.com
....
$ORIGIN uk.example.com.
@          IN      NS     ns2.example.com. 
; functionally identical to
; uk.example.com. IN NS ns2.example.com.
; ns2.example.com is the name server for uk.example.com
```

Comment: if `$ORIGIN` is missing then `@` refers to the [name of the zone](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-bind).